# Misbehaving LINQ joins

Tags: c#, linq

I have a pretty large linq query driving a section of my system, and i am trying to add in a new feature, but the joins seem to be misbehaving.

The old query used to bring back a list of videos which i used to create a view model and only list each video once, with all of the metadata displayed, `VisibleStaff`, `VisiblePlayers` and `VisibleTeams` are all IEnumerable.

Since adding the par tthat drives `VisibleStaff`, any video with entries in `VideosLinkings` where the `VideoInType` flag is set to staff, displays once for each entry, rather than once, and giving me a list of staff members as metadata for `VisibleStaff`.

I think i am missing a grouping somewhere, but i have tried multiple groups in multiple places and cannot seem to get it right.

Does anyone have any idea where my joins have gone wrong and how i would return a single Video and multiple staff in each VideoModel?

**Full Query**

```
from video in Videos
where
    video.ClubID == ClubId &&
    (VideoFilter.Category == 0 || video.VideoCategoryID == VideoFilter.Category)
join userStaff in Database.Users on video.AddedByUserID.Value equals userStaff.UserID
join videoInTeams in VideoInTeams on video.VideoID equals videoInTeams.VideoID into teamsForVideo
join playerInVideo in Database.PlayersVideos on video.VideoID equals playerInVideo.VideoId into
    playersForVideo
join soapVideoLink in Database.VideosLinkings on new {a = video.VideoID, b = VideoInType.SOAPNote}
    equals new {a = soapVideoLink.VideoId, b = soapVideoLink.VideoInType} into soapVideoLinks
join staffVideoLink in Database.VideosLinkings on new {a = video.VideoID, b = VideoInType.Staff}
    equals new {a = staffVideoLink.VideoId, b = staffVideoLink.VideoInType} into
    staffVideoLinks
from svl in staffVideoLinks.DefaultIfEmpty()
join staff in Staff on svl.VideoInKeyId equals staff.StaffID into visibleStaff 
let soapLinks = soapVideoLinks.Any(f => f.VideoInKeyId != -1)
let oldExtension =
    video.H264Version == "Uploaded"
        ? ".mp4"
        : (video.FlashVersion == "Uploaded" ? ".flv" : video.FileExtension)
where
    VideoFilter.ShowSoapVideos || (VideoFilter.ShowSoapVideos == false && soapLinks == false)
orderby video.DateTimeUploaded descending
select new VideoModel
{
    Video = video,
    Category = video.VideoCategory,
    Staff = userStaff.Staff,
    ShowDeleteOption = VideoFilter.ShowDeleteOption,
    VisibleTeams = teamsForVideo.Select(f => f.Team),
    VisiblePlayers = playersForVideo.Select(f => f.Player),
    Thumbnail =
        video.ThumbnailURL != "" && video.ThumbnailURL != null
            ? video.ThumbnailURL
            : "/Images/Videos/noimage.png",
    IsNew = false,
    IsMedicalVideo = soapLinks,
    VisibleStaff = visibleStaff,
    IsStaffVideo = staffVideoLinks.Any()
}
```

The New Lines

```
join staffVideoLink in Database.VideosLinkings on new {a = video.VideoID, b = VideoInType.Staff}
    equals new {a = staffVideoLink.VideoId, b = staffVideoLink.VideoInType} into
    staffVideoLinks
from svl in staffVideoLinks.DefaultIfEmpty()
join staff in Staff on svl.VideoInKeyId equals staff.StaffID into visibleStaff
```

Comment: Is this LINQ to SQL? What's the generated SQL?

Comment: LINQ to Entities, its around 61kb of generated SQL. Ill have to do some digging to get at it, for some reason its not as easy to get to as usual.

Comment: Np. Not even sure what good it would do me, to be honest. I'm a bit confused by what you mean with "displays once for each entry, rather than once, and giving me a list of staff members as metadata for VisibleStaff". And presumably the "from" clause was different before? In my experience, changing the "from" clause can easily introduce accidental extra rows.

Comment: _"the joins seem to be misbehaving"_ -- perhaps, but it is still highly unlikely. Much more likely it is your own code that is incorrect. _"i have tried multiple groups in multiple places and cannot seem to get it right"_ -- making random changes is no way to debug. Take a step back and _analyze_ the problem, and create _a good specification_ for what it is you are trying to do. Make sure the specification is detailed enough that there is _only one way_ to write the code. Then the code will work exactly as you want.

Comment: As written here, your question does not include enough information to be useful. It's not even clear precisely what the code you show does, nor how that's different from what you want it to do, nor have you provided [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem. If you were to do that, there's a good chance you would find the problem yourself, but if not then at least you'd have something that other people could run and debug.